# Sync Sitecore contacs to CRM - Data Exchange 0 elements were iterated

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

I am working on `Sitecore 9.0.2` and `Dynamics CRM connector 2.0.1`.

While running the pipeline batch from `Sync contacts Sitecore to CRM`, the mappings don't work. below is the log Error. The log says 0 entities were read.

**Log:**

```
ManagedPoolThread #2 16:55:49 INFO [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline batch processing. (pipeline batch: xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync) ManagedPoolThread #2 16:55:49 INFO [Data Exchange] No entities were read from xConnect. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Read Contacts from xConnect, pipeline step identifier: aee1fdb1-10a4-4cc3-9522-74c6d62b0652, endpoint: xConnect Client Endpoint, entity: contact) ManagedPoolThread #2 16:55:49 DEBUG [Data Exchange] 0 elements were iterated. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Iterate xConnect Contacts and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: ea47ccc7-5855-40a9-99b8-18cf573ff915) ManagedPoolThread #2 16:55:49 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Submit Remaining Dynamics Contacts in Queue, completed pipeline steps: 6) ManagedPoolThread #2 16:55:49 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline batch processor finished processing pipelines. (pipeline batch: xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync, completed pipelines: 1)
```

Comment: Could you extend your question with more details? It's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the Databases and Indexes, this will fix the issue. It worked for me.